# Rails 3 : Can't get form_for to work as a 'delete' following the RESTful achitecture => always giving a ROUTING ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, form-for

I have a very simple render that goes as follow:

```
<%= form_for(:relationships, :url => relationships_path, :html => {:method => 'delete'}) do |f| %>
<div><%= f.hidden_field :user_id_to_unfollow, :value => @user.id %></div>
<div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Unfollow" %></div>
<% end %>
```

When I submit this form it will always give me a

```
Routing Error
No route matches "/relationships"
```

on my page.

In my relationships controller, I have created all the propers methods:

```
def create    
...
end

def destroy    
...
end

def update    
...
end

def show    
...
end
```

And in my routes config I have made sure to allow all routes for the relationships controller

```
resources :relationships
```

But I can't seem to get into the destroy method of the controller :(

However if I remove the

```
:html => {:method => 'delete'}
```

method parameter in the form_for then I get to the create method of the controller no pb.

I don't get it....

Alex

ps: this is the rake routes results for relationships:

```
relationships GET    /relationships(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"relationships"}
              POST   /relationships(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"relationships"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should point the `delete` request to single resource url eg. `relationships/4325`. Run `rake routes` to view what url/verb combinations are valid.

--edit

Routes for relationship resources:

```
resources :relationships, :only => [:index, :create, :destroy]
```

Unfollow button (creates a form for itself):

```
= button_to "Unfollow", relationship_path(relationship), :method => 'delete'
```

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean ? But how would I do that ? I don't see sorry... I don't know what to change to create that destroy route.